# Selecting layer to search on all pages

Tags: vba, coreldraw

This is part of the code im working with;

```
Dim s As Shape

Dim p As Page, numberPage As Integer
Dim i&

Dim WhatSamp As String

WhatSamp = "Sample1"

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Pages.Count
ActiveDocument.Pages(i).Activate

For Each s In ActiveDocument.ActivePage.Shapes

If s.Type = cdrTextShape Then

     If InStr(1, s.Text.Story, WhatSamp) > 0 Then
     ActivePage.Layers("Sample").Visible = True
     ActivePage.Layers("Sample").Printable = True

     End If

End If

Next

Next i
```

The code im working with is much longer but i believe this is the relevant part.

It searches for my text on the page (Sample1) then displays and makes printable the layer called "Sample".

I think because I have a ridiculous amount of needed layers it takes forever to run

So, Im trying to get it to search for my text only on a specific layer that exists on each page called "Style" but i cant seem to figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Let me know if more information is needed

Comment: All your's question is so simple!! Use help on visual basic for Corel Draw [some example](http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/dvba_pg.pdf) or [object model](http://dev.oberonplace.com/vba/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test on what layer is object "S" use if

```
 if S.Layer.Name="Style" then
```

then

```
If InStr(1, s.Text.Story, WhatSamp) > 0 Then
 ActivePage.Layers("Sample").Visible = True
 ActivePage.Layers("Sample").Printable = True
```